# In the Linux Kernel what file/process controls the assignment of permissions to memory pages?

Tags: permissions, virtual-memory

A given memory page may be writable, readable or executable. What *kernal* source code file *in the linux kernal* describes the setting of these rights? What process *or kernal data structure* would set the rights?

To use slightly more clear terminology: What *source code file* of the *linux kernal* sets the NX bit in Linux systems? On a running system where might I find the data structure that governs this?

This is not a question about a 3rd party application trying to set the nx bit.

Comment: are you confusing file permissions with memory page?

Comment: No. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit, and the concept as expressed on BSD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX

Comment: There is no "file" or specific process that does this, it is function of the Linux kernel.

Comment: @mdpc my sense of the question is that they're asking what specific kernel thread sets this up. The question isn't related to Linux fundamentals so I think it's safe to assume they know the difference between POSIX permissions and shared memory permissions.

Comment: By file, I mean the source file that implements this in the kernal. Also this is a relevant question here, so I'm not sure why I'm being down voted.

Comment: @baordog, good question +1. I would edit and add the fact that you looking for a kernel source file though, it makes it much more clear.